# Arrays: inputing data

Tags: java, arrays

this method is suppose to ask the user for the file name that is already created that contains  list of numbers, if file does not exist i have to let the user know. im having trouble figuring out how to assign the numbers in the file to a new array?

```
public static int[] inputData() throws IOException
{
      int count = 0;
      System.out.print("enter input filename: ");
      File myFile = new File("input.txt");

      if(!myFile.exists())
      {
         System.out.print("file does not exist ");
         System.exit(0);
      }
      Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
      while(inputFile.hasNext() && count < ARRAY_SIZE)
         {
             array[count++] = input.nextInt();
         }    
      return array[];
   }
```

Comment: How does it fail so far?

Comment: AM I missing a piece of the code or did you never declare the array, you can declare the array using int[] array = new array[size] with size being the size of the array.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn how to declare and allocate a new array, which you'll pass back. It looks like it'll be an array of `int`, and you'll make it a certain size (is `ARRAY_SIZE` defined somewhere already?) when you call `new`. See the [official tutorial on arrays](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

(As a note, it's usually a bad idea to use an external upper limit in a `for` loop over an array. The array comes with a built-in `length` you can use that will always be the correct size.)

Answer (score -1):

Where are you defining the variable array?

your problem is going to be that you don't know how big you need the array to be. The best option is to use an ArrayList as this allows dynamic sizing. (As a result it needs to be a list of Integers rather than ints)

```
public static Integer[] inputData() throws IOException
{
  List<Integer> fileData = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  int count = 0;
  System.out.print("enter input filename: ");
  File myFile = new File("input.txt");
  if(!myFile.exists())
  {
     System.out.print("file does not exist ");
     System.exit(0);
  }
  Scanner inputFile = new Scanner(myFile);
  while(inputFile.hasNext())
  {
     fileData.add(inputFile.nextInt());
  }    
  return fileData.toArray(new Integer[fileData.size()]);
}
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the asker's question, which is about learning to use arrays specifically (it looks like for a class).

Comment: The way i understood the question is "I need to get these numbers in to an array", that's what i've shown them how to do. they end up with an array of integers based on the file input. How does that not answer the question? (which makes me ask why you downvoted this...)

Comment: Fair enough, and I'll remove the downvote if an edit permits, but the question appears to be intended to teach the OP to use Java array syntax. Additionally, you return an `Integer[]`, not an `int[]`, which is probably relevant for the assignment.

Comment: Thanks. The question is a bit vague about what they're trying to do, whether its learn arrays, or achieve a goal. I guess we understood it differently. I did mention that it would be a list of Integers rather than ints, due to the use of a list, and the changed the array to match (partially because I was too lazy to write a loop to convert them myself...).

Comment: Of course, you could really go off the deep end and use a Java 8 lambda to convert...